# Python selenium how to scrape list of values from website

Tags: python, selenium

I have a list of job roles on this website that I want to scrape. The code I am using is below:

```
driver.get('https://jobs.ubs.com/TGnewUI/Search/home/HomeWithPreLoad?partnerid=25008&siteid=5012&PageType=searchResults&SearchType=linkquery&LinkID=6017#keyWordSearch=&locationSearch=')
job_roles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a')

for job_roles in job_roles:
    text = job_roles.text
    print(text)
```

With this code, I am able to retrieve the first role which is: Business Analyst - IB Credit Risk Change

I am unable to retrieve the other roles, can someone kindly assist

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case all the job names have the two CSS classes `jobProperty` and `jobtitle`.

So, since you want *all* the jobs, I recommend selecting by [CSS selector](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-elements-by-css-selectors).

The following example should work:

```
driver.get('https://jobs.ubs.com/TGnewUI/Search/home/HomeWithPreLoad?partnerid=25008&siteid=5012&PageType=searchResults&SearchType=linkquery&LinkID=6017#keyWordSearch=&locationSearch=')

job_roles = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.jobProperty.jobtitle')
for job_roles in job_roles:
    text = job_roles.text
    print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks thats perfect!. Can I ask why the .jobProperty.jobtitle contains the full stops around jobProperty

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the xPath, you were very close. Your xPath specifically only selects the first li element (`li[1]`). By changing it to just `li`, it will find all matching xPaths:

```
driver.get('https://jobs.ubs.com/TGnewUI/Search/home/HomeWithPreLoad?partnerid=25008&siteid=5012&PageType=searchResults&SearchType=linkquery&LinkID=6017#keyWordSearch=&locationSearch=')
job_roles = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/ul/li/div[2]/div[1]/span/a')

for job_roles in job_roles:
    text = job_roles.text
    print(text)
```